# Why is there no term for potential energy in the expression for total energy of a particle?

Tags: special-relativity, potential-energy, mass-energy

In my physics class I studied that the total energy of any particle is given by,

$E=K+m c^{2}=\frac{m c^{2}}{\sqrt{1-v^{2} / c^{2}}}=\gamma m c^{2}$ = $\left(m c^{2}\right)^{2}+(p c)^{2}$

Let us focus on the first expression :
$E=K+m c^{2}$
Here $K$ is the kinetic energy of the particle given by

$K=\frac{m c^{2}}{\sqrt{1-v^{2} / c^{2}}}-m c^{2}=(\gamma-1) m c^{2}$

Now in the total energy expression of the particle there is kinetic energy as well as the rest mass energy of the particle. But what about the potential energy of a particle? Doesn't potential energy also play a role in the total energy of particle? For instance the total energy of an electron revolving around the nucleus is given by the sum of its kinetic energy, potential energy and rest mass energy of the electron, right? What about the potential energy? Why is there no term of potential energy in the total energy expression of the particle?

Comment: More on [potential energy in SR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potential-energy+special-relativity).

Answer (score 2):

Potential energy is usually frame dependent. When we consider potential energy, we are measuring it from within a particular reference frame (like a mass at a certain height $h$ has a potential energy $mgh$ from where *you* define $h=0$).  In relativity, we want to be able to define physical quantities in any frame of reference. Generalizing potential energy to all cases in relativity would cause problems.

Also, in your example of the potential energy of an electron in an atom$^1$, when we bring the electron closer to, or further from the nucleus of the atom, relativistically speaking, we have increased/decreased the rest energy (and therefore rest mass) of the system, so that potential energy actually contributes to the rest energy of the system. The potential energy can therefore be considered part of the rest energy. And so we need not add a separate term for the potential energy in the total energy for such a system of interacting particles.

$^1$ We can still have potentials, but the simple model of a particle having its own potential energy will not always work when relativistic effects come into play. Relativistic energy is purposely defined such that is it conserved in all inertial frames.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The potential energy ($V$) is missing
in that expression for total energy.
The correct total energy would be:
$$E=V+K+mc^2$$
or
$$E=V+\gamma mc^2$$

May be your course in special relativity just begins with free
particles (i.e. no potential energy) for didactic reasons,
and will introduce interactions (i.e. potential energy) later on.

However, the equation above is not the end of the story.
Consider a particle in an electromagnetic field. Then the potential
energy is $$V=q\Phi$$
where $q$ is the charge of the particle and $\Phi$ is the [electric potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential).
But in addition to the electric potential $\Phi$ you also need to consider
the [magnetic potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_vector_potential) $\mathbf{A}$.
Then the relation between energy, momentum and the potentials is
$$(E-q\Phi)^2 = (mc^2)^2 + (\mathbf{p}-q\mathbf{A})^2c^2$$
or resolved for the energy
$$E = q\Phi + \sqrt{(mc^2)^2 + (\mathbf{p}-q\mathbf{A})^2c^2}.$$

Here the first part is the potential energy ($V$),
and the second part (the square root) can be interpreted
as the sum of kinetic energy and rest mass energy ($K+mc^2)$.